# gzip compression on AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker

How can we enable gzip compression on AWS using a docker file for react js application?
We want to enable GZIP compression for artifacts flowing from Server to a browser.
In IIS we have used such a setting. But we are not aware of how to set this in Docker file in react js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of server to enable gzip, like in your earlier case you used IIS, mostly I use Nginx to enable gzip, you can do from Nginx config, 
but for that, you have to use Nginx base Image to server Reactjs app.

Here is DockerFile for nginx

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY ./ .

RUN yarn run build_prod

FROM nginx:1.17.6-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
bash \
curl

#config nginx and supervisord
COPY ConfigFiles/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ConfigFiles/site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf

RUN mkdir -p mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && \
mkdir -p /run/nginx && \
mkdir -p /var/www/frontend && \
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf 

WORKDIR /var/www

#COPY dist ./frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist ./frontend
```

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';    
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/javascript application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-otf application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype font/otf font/ttf image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/javascript text/plain text/xml image/gif;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

site.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #server_name d;

    root /var/www/frontend;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root /var/www/frontend;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```